# child_process.exec/spawn triggers callback/close with npm install command (via Gulp / Shipit)

Tags: node.js, promise, gulp, child-process

- I'm using [Shipit](https://github.com/shipitjs/shipit) for deployment.
- On deploy, Shipit checks out the current Git Sha, to a tmp directory, then  I run `npm install` followed by `gulp build`, then proceed with the deploy.
- Shipit uses Orchestrator for it's task flow, as Gulp does.
- Shipit has it's own CLI, so I can deploy with `shipit development deploy`.

Everything thing above works. What I'm trying to do is create a `gulp deploy` task that will initialize Shipit directly, instead of using the CLI. Looks something like this:

```
gulp.task('shipit:deploy', function() {
  var deployToEnv = argv['deploy-to'] || false;
  var shipit;
  return inquirer.prompt([{
    type: 'list',
    name: 'deployToEnv',
    default: deployToEnv,
    message: 'Deploy to environment:',
    choices: envs
  }]).then(function(answers) {
    deployToEnv = answers.deployToEnv;
    shipit = new Shipit({environment: deployToEnv});
    shipit.initialize();
    shipit.start('deploy');
  });
});
```

Corresponding shipit config:

```
  shipit.initConfig(config);
  shipit.blTask('build', function() {
    return shipit.local('npm install --silent', {
      cwd: shipit.config.workspace
    }).then(function() {
      return shipit.local('gulp build', {
        cwd: shipit.config.workspace
      });
    });
  });

  shipit.on('fetched', function() {
    shipit.start('build');
  });
```

Things appear to work with one problem: it doesn't actually perform the `npm install`!

`Running "npm install --silent" on local.
Running "gulp build" on local.`

So, it would seem something in the `npm install` command is prematurely resolving the promise, but I'm not sure how or why.

I had a similar problem (just using shipit cli) with npm warnings, which is when I discovered using the --silent arg solved that.

As a test, I left the code as is, but replaced `npm install --silent` with `sleep 10`. Sure enough, it waited for 10 seconds before executing `gulp build`. So, it would seem it is something specific with the `npm install` command.

Any help is appreciated!

### Update #1:

`shipit.local` uses `child_process.exec`. I tried converting this to use `child_process.spawn`, but had the same result.

### Update #2:

If I change the command to `sudo npm install`, things work as expected! So...what does this mean, and how can I avoid running it with `sudo`?

### Update #3:

Still unable to do this without sudo, but I tried adding the `--verbose` flag with these results:

Without `sudo`:

```
@ npm info it worked if it ends with ok
@ npm verb cli [ '/Users/timkelty/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/bin/node',
@ npm verb cli   '/Users/timkelty/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/bin/npm',
@ npm verb cli   'install',
@ npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
@ npm info using npm@2.5.1
@ npm info using node@v0.12.0
@ npm verb install where, deps [ '/Users/timkelty/tmp/edwards-garment-website', [] ]
@ npm verb install where, peers [ '/Users/timkelty/tmp/edwards-garment-website', [] ]
@ npm info preinstall edwards-garment-website@1.1.0
@ npm info build /Users/timkelty/tmp/edwards-garment-website
@ npm verb linkStuff [ false, false, false, '/Users/timkelty/tmp' ]
@ npm info linkStuff edwards-garment-website@1.1.0
@ npm verb linkBins edwards-garment-website@1.1.0
@ npm verb linkMans edwards-garment-website@1.1.0
@ npm verb rebuildBundles edwards-garment-website@1.1.0
@ npm info install edwards-garment-website@1.1.0
@ npm info postinstall edwards-garment-website@1.1.0
@ npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
@ npm info ok
Running "gulp build" on local.
@ [15:14:32] Local gulp not found in ~/tmp/edwards-garment-website
@ [15:14:32] Try running: npm install gulp
'build' errored after 755 ms
Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c gulp build
```

With `sudo`:

```
Running "sudo npm install --verbose" on local.
@ npm info it worked if it ends with ok
@ npm verb cli [ '/Users/timkelty/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/bin/node',
@ npm verb cli   '/Users/timkelty/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/bin/npm',
@ npm verb cli   'install',
@ npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
@ npm info using npm@2.5.1
@ npm info using node@v0.12.0
@ npm verb install where, deps [ '/Users/timkelty/tmp/edwards-garment-website',
@ npm verb install   [ 'Select2',
@ npm verb install     'autoprefixer-core',
@ npm verb install     'babel',
```

...so for some reason, when running without sudo, the npm install command seems to think it doesn't have any dependencies to install, so it finishes without error and continues to my next task.

Comment: Can you use `npm install` without `--silent` and print  in then console.log(res.stdout); and console.log(res.stderr)?

Comment: @vanadium23 in the `child_process.exec` callback, both stdout and stderr are empty strings: https://gist.github.com/4c0c905e2ab517806915

Comment: just to make sure that is not the permission error  can you try make change permission to 755 and run script?

Comment: @vanadium23 Sure, but on what path? I did `chmod -R 755` on the dir I'm running the `npm install` command from, same result.

Comment: i have antoher idea after a good sleep. Can we make task `echo "$(which npm) test" >> test.file` instead of `sleep 10`. Why it is needed? First we know if gulp can create file, second we know if gulp can use npm and which one.

Comment: @vanadium23 the contents of test.file are `/Users/timkelty/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/bin/npm test`

Comment: @vanadium23 see update #2 about `sudo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution!

The problem was that I was trying to install `devDependencies`, but when I ran the `gulp deploy` command, NODE_ENV was set to production, which does not install devDependencies.

Therefore, changing the command to `NODE_ENV=development npm install` seems to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

After update #2, I have more options to write why this combination don't work/ First of all, we need to figure out which user a execute the commands. To do this, you need to execute command `whoami` and see result (you can do it through ssh or shipit task). The direct question is what priveleges don't have user to install packages.

**Possible solution #1:**

User don't have rights on tmp folder. We can check it via `ls -ld /path/to/tmp`, expected output:

```
drwxrwxrwt 13 root root 280 May  8 19:42 /tmp
```

You need to verify, that all users can write in tmp dir: drwxrwxrwx. If not, you can set by `chmod -R 755`.

**Possible solution #2:**

Execute on `npm` is granted only on owner user/group, and our user don't have ones. We can check it via `ls -lL $(which npm)`. Expected output:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1881 Apr 19 07:12 /usr/../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
```

If there is no permission x on file, then execute `sudo chmod +x $(which npm)`.

**UPDATE:**
After this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137079/node-js-express-install-no-readme-data) there is might be also problem not with your tmp folder, but with debug folder for npm. Try to search for one & check permission.

Hope it's all options that we can met.

Comment: perms of `/tmp`: ``lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel``

Comment: @TimKelty it's symlink that is writable only to root/sudo, try `ls -lLd /tmp`

Comment: `ls -lLd /tmp
drwxr-xr-x 22 root wheel 748 May 11 07:44 /tmp`

Comment: To avoid that whole permsissions issue, I changed the tmp location to `~/tmp/`. Still having the issue. Trying solution #2 now.

Comment: `ls -lL $(which npm)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 timkelty staff 1928 Feb  6 15:42 /Users/timkelty/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/bin/npm`

Comment: Debug folder: ```ls -lLd ~/.npm/debug
drwxr-xr-x 14 timkelty staff 476 Mar 13 17:12 /Users/timkelty/.npm/debug```

Comment: Anything else I should try, @vanadium23?

Comment: @TimKelty as far as I can see, if with `sudo` it installs, then it definitely a file permission issue. Guess we don't notice the elephant. :-(

Comment: see update #3 above. It would seem that npm install doesn't think it has any deps to install when not running as sudo. That make any sense?

Comment: I seem to getting to the root of this:
All the deps that are supposed to be installed in this case are `devDependencies`. I discovered that if I switch them to just `dependencies`, it works.